# Add entities to Unit of Work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an entity getting persisted and in some case other entities need to be created and persisted with it.

Current use case is when toggling a boolean property in the list view of EasyAdminBundle I need to create entities and persist them if that property is set to true.

I thought to do it in a `preUpdate` event, thus I took a look at the unit of work  interface and tried to understand it a little.

I can access methods like:

```
$event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityUpdates()
```

and

```
$event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsetions()
```

So, I dumped these contents and got 1 entry for the entity to update and empty array for the insertions.

Then added new entities doing:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->scheduleForInsert($entity);
```

after all I dumped again entites scheduled to update and insert and everything figured correctly.

```
array:1 [▼
  "000000006b3c425d000000005d5d714c" => Entity {#1045 ▶}
]
```

The array key for this entity in the insertions schedule is the same featuring in the updates schedule.

Unfortunately no insert queries was performed.

Is there a way (as it seemed at first glance) to add objects to the current unit of work in order to modify data to update/persist inside a preUpdate event?

**EDIT (listener code):**

```
/**
     * @param Market $market
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $event
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     */
    public function preUpdate(Market $market, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $uow = $event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();
        $changeset = $event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($market);

        if(isset($changeset['boolean_field']) && count($changeset['boolean_field']) == 2){
            if(!$changeset['boolean_field'][1]){//THIS IS NO CONCERN AT THE MOMENT
                $activations = $event->getEntityManager()->getRepository('BaseMapping:MarketWatchedByUser')
                    ->findBy(['market' => $market]);

                foreach ($activations as $a) {
                    $event->getEntityManager()->remove($a);
                }
            }
            else{//THIS IS WHAT IS BEING TESTED
                $users = $event->getEntityManager()->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
                    ->findAll();

                foreach ($users as $u) {
                    $activation = new MarketWatchedByUser();
                    $activation->setUser($u);
                    $activation->setMarket($market);
                    dump($event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->isScheduledForInsert($activation));
                    $event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->scheduleForInsert($activation);
                    dump($event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->isScheduledForInsert($activation));
                }
                $event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->commit();//ENDLESS LOOP
                dump($event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityUpdates());
                dump($event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now, we know more. The answer is, you shouldn't do this that way. `preUpdate` won't allow for such operations check (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate). Why don't you do this operation in Model/Handler/<wherever you have logic>?

Comment: because the logic is implemented by the easyadminbundle and I'd like to avoid overriding its controllers.. basically, as I toggle a property from the list view (the entity gets updated) I need code to be exeuted (and entities being created) @mleko

Comment: I would go for custom action

Comment: @mleko if you want to argument and build up an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Or I can do it.. I missed the point that what I was trying to do wasn't allowed in doctrine. I got misled by playing with the Unit of Work interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations you are trying to do aren't allowed in entity listeners, [preUpdate](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) is especially restrictive.

Also this looks like business logic. I would suggest moving logic to Model/Handler.

You can try adding [custom action](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/tutorials/custom-actions.html) to not have to fiddle in EasyAdminBundle internals.